# Cordova (PhoneGap) InAppBrowser crashes when app resumes from background

Tags: ios, cordova

Occasionally, when the app wakes up having entered the background, the InAppBrowser component disappears from the screen (crashes?), removing the content that was being displayed before the app entered the background. It fails silently with no errors or warnings in Xcode.

Does anyone have a solution for this, or even a suggestion for how to approach fixing it? I'm happy to try suggestions that are either javascript or objective-c based (or both!).

Incidentally, I'm working with Cordova 3.3 for iOS.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

In cordova 3.3 InAppBrowser plugin is not working. Try with some other lower version.

Comment: It works almost all of the time, only occasionally it fails to reload